# @import less file inside another less is not working

Tags: css, less, umbraco, dotless

I have followed this blog post: [url](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/recommendations/recommended-reading-for-web-developers/less-and-integration-into-umbraco) to integrate less with Umbraco. Also, while working on my mac, I was using SimpLESS app to compile my less to css which was working successfully. I have uploaded all my less files on the server, with a proper mime type set on the virtual directory. The website doesn't show any file not found or any other error but this [url](http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/scripts/less/bootstrap.less) simply shows the content of my less file and doesn't compile as it was doing locally.

Steps followed:

1. Added dotless.core.dll to bin folder.
2. HTTP handler added to web.config.
3. References a less file in master.aspx
4. All the less files are under Scripts folder.

Comment: With Rails, the production server typically runs the app in the production environment, which doesn't compile assets by default, it expects them to be precompiled to improve performance. I'm not familiar with umbraco, but maybe something similar is going on? I've done a quick search on the terms `umbraco preset assets` and found https://gist.github.com/2883686, for example.

Comment: @JasperKennis the concept of preset assets and umbraco is really a new   for me to work with. But the steps I have added is same when one needs to install less on .net local project. Not able to figure out the reason why server is not rendering less.

Comment: I've googled some more, seems that Umbraco uses a config file (xml formatted). Is there an option that you might be able to set to tell your site to always compile assets on the fly?

Comment: I think I'm putting you on the wrong track here, maybe you should ignore my comments;)

Comment: @JasperKennis modifying the handler has helped. server can now render less files.

Comment: I don't know the umbraco terms, but this is relevant I guess: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/recommendations/recommended-reading-for-web-developers/less-and-integration-into-umbraco

Comment: yes and this is the same post that I have referenced in my question. Thanks @JasperKennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working when as per IIS6 the handler for less under web.config was `<!-- LESS -->
      <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />`

But when I changed the above to `<remove name="DotLessCss" />
 <add name="DotLessCss" verb="*" path="*.less" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core"` for IIS7.5, the server was then able to render less.